# How to remove an object from a list, if that said object's list is empty? (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object

Working in python 3. Let's say I have created a class for an object, My_Object. My_Object has a variable which is a list of numbers. It also has a function that allows you to remove numbers from the list within the object.

Now I create a list containing several My_Objects, some which have had their lists emptied and others that still have some numbers in their lists. How would I go about removing any objects from my_list whose objects have no values in their lists?

So in the example below, I would want to remove x from my_list as x has an empty list, while keeping y and z in my_list so that printing my_list would produce - [2, 3] [1, 2, 3] instead of [] [2, 3] [1, 2, 3]

Tried to figure it out on my own, but can't seem to figure out how to fully remove an object from a list based on its contents.

```
class My_Object:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [1, 2, 3]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.a)

    def remove_item(self, item):
        self.a.remove(item)

x = My_Object()
y = My_Object()
z = My_Object()

my_list = [x, y, z]

x.remove_item(1)
x.remove_item(2)
x.remove_item(3)

y.remove_item(1)

print(*my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out shortly after posting. This seemed to get me what I wanted:

`my_list = [x for x in my_list if x.a != []]`

Comment: just `if x` is enough, empty lists being falsy

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Or `list(filter(None, my_list))`

Comment: Yeah tried that before, but couldn't get it to work for my case. I think my initial issue was that I was trying to check if the object itself was empty, rather than checking if the list within the object was empty.

Comment: maybe `list(filter(lambda x: x.a, my_list))` anyway, stick to the list comprehension, more readable

Comment: You could make the `My_Object` type have a boolean value by writing it a `__bool__` method if you want. Or alternatively, you could add the "is my inner list empty" check to the `remove_item` method, which could return a bool to tell the caller if the object is now empty.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any object that has empty list in your code here is a simple algorithm

- first loop through each object in your list
- check if the object's list length == 0 which means empty
- if so remove it else do nothing

here a simple code for that

```
# go through each element 
for obj in my_list : 
    # check if its list empty 
    if len(obj.a) == 0 :
       # if true remove it 
       my_list.remove(obj)
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

With list comps

```
my_list = [x for x in my_list if x]
```

or getting silly

```
my_list = [*filter(bool, my_list)]
```

Comment: How does they work?  The class doesn't define a `__bool__` method.

Answer (score -1):

You can either remove an item from a list by it's value or by the index at which it is in the list. Below is the code where I demonstrate both i.e. removing an item from list by it's value and by it's index

```
class My_Object:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [1, 2, 3]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.a)

    def remove_item(self, item):
        self.a.remove(item)

x = My_Object()
y = My_Object()
z = My_Object()

my_list = [x, y, z]

# If you want to remove object from list by its value than
my_list.remove(y)  # This will remove y object from my_list

# Now my_list has two elements in it which are [x, z]
# If you want to remove object from list by its value than
my_list.pop(0)  # This will remove x object from my_list

# Now my_list has one element in it which is[z]
```

If you do not know the value of the object than you can not remove it by its value so what you can do is that you can iterate through the list and search for a particular property of the object and if you match that property than simply remove that object from the list by `pop()`